# Why the space complexity of this function is m*n?

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

Why is the space complexity of this function **n*m** and not **m*log(n)**? 
as in each function recursive, it takes `(m*2^i)/2^i = m` and `i` go from `0` to `log(n)` so it has to be **m*logn**, what am I missing here?

```
void f3(int n, int m) {
    double *p;
    int i;
    if (n <= 1)
        return;
    p = (double *)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
    if (p == NULL)
        return;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if (i < m)
            p[i] = i;
    printf("%f ", p[0]);
    free(p);
    f3(n / 2, m * 2);
    f3(n / 2, m * 2);
}
```

Comment: Add some logging to see what the behaviour is.

Comment: Why are you dividing by 2^i?

Comment: @melpomene Sorry I fix it

Comment: @melpomene because each recursive calling you get n/2, so for the first calls you get n/2 and for the second n/4(n/(2^2)) and the third - n/8(n/(2^3))  and so on ....

Comment: OK, but why are you dividing `m` by `2^i` if you're talking about `n`?

Comment: @melpomene each recursion occupy 2^i*m when allocating the memory, (malloc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an (approximate) invariance in your recursion:

```
n * m = (n/2) * (m*2)
```

Thus when your recursion goes deeper, `m` gets larger and larger until `n = 1`, where `m` is `m*n` at the beginning.

You memory allocation is only

```
p = (double*)malloc(m * sizeof(double));
```

And it's `free`ed  before going to the next recursion. So the biggest `m` is the maximal space complexity, which is `O(mn)`.